# How do I detect my software is running in my Wix MSI?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have an MSI which is going to install/update a driver.  However I want to detect if the driver is running and shut it down before starting the install.  I need to do this silently as the customers are using active directory to deploy to computers.

Using the WIX install scripts, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I am missing something here but if you need to shut down a driver before installing, then a custom action would be the best approach, in my opinion.

You can write custom actions either by using VB scripts or calling into managed assemblies. I like the latter more (personal preference of C# instead of VB). The custom action in WiX source file would look like that:

Declare the binary element which represents the assembly to be called into:

```html
<Binary Id="BIN_DriverManagement" SourceFile=".\DriverManagement.CA.dll />
```

Then define the custom action, calling the method of the assembly:

```html
<CustomAction Id="CACT_ShutDownDriverAction" BinaryKey="BIN_DriverManagement" DllEntry="ShutDownDriver" />
```

The last step would be schedulling the custom action into the installation sequence:

```html
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="CACT_ShutDownDriverAction" After="LaunchConditions" />
</InstallexecuteSequence>
```

Actually, I am not sure when such custom action should be scheduled, it depends on the requirements.

The custom action function, implemented in C# should be prepended with [CustomAction] attribute from the Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller namespace, so it might look like this:

```c#
[Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.CustomAction]
public static ActionResult ShutDownDriver(Session session)
{
    // Shut down the driver here.
}
```

Comment: Isn't it a bit difficult to use c#?  You cannot be sure the .NET runtime is installed.

Comment: Sure, this might be a problem but custom actions are not limited to .NET code. You could execute a custom native code executable using the CustomAction's FileKey attribute.